# first time using .h and multiple .cpp files in one project, errorssss :(

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, search

second post on StackOverflow. I just have some general questions as to why my program is acting the way it is, I don't want help in completing it I was just absent from class on Friday and apparently I missed a lot. 
I'm tasked to design a program that contains 3 .cpp and 2 .h files, in essence it will search and sort through arrays of strings using the bubble sort, insertion sort, selection sort methods and sequential and binary search. We are then supposed to benchmark each method to figure out which is the fastest.

I am just confused as to why the compiler keeps yelling at me, it's not making much sense I've been sitting here for about an hour fiddling around with different options or typing the code in differently but to no avail.

My header file

```
const int NOT_FOUND = -1;
int sequentialSearch(string a[], string needle, int length );
```

JohnSearch.cpp

```
#include "JohnSearch.h"
#include <string>

int sequentialSearch(string copied[], string needle, int length)
{
int i;   // iteration variable

// look at every element to see if it is the same as needle
for( i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    if( copied[i] == needle )
        return i;
return NOT_FOUND;
}
```

TestSearch.cpp

```
#include "JohnSearch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

/*
** printArray(title,a,length): print out title and then the contents of array a
*/
void printArray(string title, string ref[], int length )
{
    int i;      // array iteration

    cout << title << ": \n";
    for( i = 0; i < length; i++ )
        cout<<setw(20)<<ref[i]<<"\n";
}

int main(void)
{
string reference[]={"John", "Allen", "Kevin", "Elisabeth"};
const int SZ=sizeof(reference)/sizeof(reference[0]);
string copied[SZ];

printArray("Reference", reference, SZ); 


// sequential search (on unsorted array)
cout<<"Search.sequential(ref,Kevin):\t"<<sequentialSearch(reference, "Kevin", SZ)<<endl;


system("Pause");
return 0;
```

}

Errors

```
johnsearch.h(2): error C2065: 'string' : undeclared identifier
johnsearch.h(2): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'a'
johnsearch.h(2): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
testjohnsearch.cpp(28): error C3861: 'copyArray': identifier not found
testjohnsearch.cpp(31): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments
johnsearch.h(2): error C2065: 'string' : undeclared identifier
johnsearch.h(2): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'a'
johnsearch.h(2): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
johnsearch.cpp(7): error C2065: 'string' : undeclared identifier
johnsearch.cpp(7): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'copied'
johnsearch.cpp(7): error C2374: 'sequentialSearch' : redefinition; multiple initialization
johnsearch.h(2) : see declaration of 'sequentialSearch'
johnsearch.cpp(7): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
johnsearch.cpp(8): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
johnsearch.cpp(8): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

I'm obviously doing something completely and utterly wrong. I need JohnSearch.cpp for JohnSearch.h right? The forward declaration of the function in JohnSearch.h is defined in JohnSearch.cpp so I need those two files correct?

I'm just really confused. The example program we are supposed to modify has 2 .h files and 3 .cpp files. 2 of those .cpp files correspond with the 2 .h files so thats why I assumed I would also need 2 .h files and 3 .cpp files.

String is still undefined.

Comment: What does the compiler say?

Comment: `std::string` maybe?  The string class is in the std namespace.

Comment: We have not learned class structures yet :( @elimirks the compiler says "johnsearch.h(2): error C2065: 'string' : undeclared identifier"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> johnsearch.h(2): error C2065: 'string' : undeclared identifier

Your header file uses `string` , so you'll need to include `<string>`, before your declarations. You also need to qualify it as std::string since the string class resides in the `std` namespace

So your header file becomes:

```
#include <string>
const int NOT_FOUND = -1;
int sequentialSearch(std::string a[], std::string needle, int length );
```

(you should also use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your header files)

Your JohnSearch.cpp also uses string, again, since `string` is in the `std` namespace, you'll get errors if you don't use `std::string`

In your TestSearch.cpp, you have a `using namespace std;` at the top, you could do the same in JohnSearch.cpp too, that way you can use `string` instead of `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, *simplify*. You can boil the code down to something like this:

```
#include "JohnSearch.h"

void sequentialSearch(string needle)
{
}
```

and get the same error (and maybe a warning about an unused parameter).

Yes, `string` is a type of variable, but it's not innate in the C++ language itself, it's in one of the standard libraries, something you have to tell the compiler about:

```
#include "JohnSearch.h"
#include <string>
using std::string;

void sequentialSearch(string needle)
{
}
```

Comment: I've included <string> but it didn't work, I just tried using std::string; and it removed the errors. Why is this?

Comment: @JtWeidenfeller: it has to do with *namespaces*. If you just include the library header file, the compiler doesn't know that you want it to look there for `string`. If you just say `using std::string;`, the compiler doesn't know about any such library. The fact that you succeeded with `using...` and without `#include...` almost certainly means that `JohnSearch.h` includes the library header (perhaps indirectly, by including something that includes it).

Comment: I completely reworded my entire post to give a much better description of whats actually happening. I've included all the code I have thus far and the errors. Even with #include string I still get the error that string is undefined. :/

Comment: You declare `sequentialSearch`, which takes a `string` argument (and a `string[]` argument), *before* you tell the compiler what a `string` is. Put `#include <string>` and `using std::string;` at the top of the header, and it will correct at least some of the errors. And ***simplify***, so that you can tackle the problems one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In your header file that you include, you need to have the exact same signature than your function in the cpp file.

Also dont forget to #include <string>, and then use a string like : std::string

E.g.

```
Int function(int number, int number2);
```

And in your cpp

```
Int function(int number, int number2)
{
    // code
}
```

Signature is "int function(int, int)".